# Failed Python3 imports when calling files in same/sub/super directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, directory-structure

I know there are many questions related to import errors and file/folder structure, but none seem to have the same structure as my file tree I have been struggling with ordering my files and importing for several hours and would appreciate some guidance.

My file tree is as follows

```
-MainFolder
   -program.py
   -HelperFolder
       -helper1.py
       -helper2.py
       -HelperTestFolder
           -helpertest.py
```

The helper functions need to import each other and the program.py has to import helper1 and helper2. The helpertest.py function has to import helper1.py and helper2.py

I've tried using an `__init__.py` file for the HelperFolder, various combinations of `import .file`, `from file import *`, etc. No matter what I do, I seem to get thrown some error (NameErrors, ImportErrors, etc) by either the helper1 or helper2.py file, the program.py file, or the helpertest.py file.

I'm sorry for the vague question, but is there a "right" way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

In program.py:

```
from HelperFolder import helper1, helper2
```

In helper1.py:

```
import helper2
```

It can be tricky to manage circular dependencies.  You're sure you need `helper1` and `helper2` to import each other?
In helpertest.py:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append( os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/..' ))
import helper1
import helper2
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim Roberts. I removed the circular dependencies between `helper1` and `helper2` such that `helper2` no longer has to import `helper1`. I also had to add the `sys.path.append( os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))` to `helper1` in order to import `helper2`. Although my code is admittedly more complex than the simplified tree I presented, so there may be other issues lurking...